# Biztalk scripting functoid - String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, scripting, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I need to get String e.g. "2015-09-21 21:49" to DateTime so I could insert it to Oracle DataBase. I'm using C# Scripting Functoid. Original FlatFile String is "21092015242149".

This is my script so far...

```
public String MyANALYZETIME(string param1)
{    
    param1=param1.Replace("\"","");

    param1=param1.Substring(4,4) + '-' + param1.Substring(2,2) + '-' + param1.Substring(0,2) + ' ' + param1.Substring(10,2) + ':' + param1.Substring(12,2);´   
    return param1;
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?  e.g. What does not work correctly?

Comment: The returned value must be type "DateTime" and not "String". I have tried parse and other stuff but C# scripting functoid does not understand eg. "parse"...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string DateConversion(string inputDate, string inputDateFormat,string destinationDateFormat)
{
    string strReturn = string.Empty;           
    var formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDate, inputDateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    strReturn = formattedDate.ToString(destinationDateFormat);              
    return strReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.Parse method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your returned string.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. This is not a prettiest one but it's working!

```
public string FormatDate(string param1){
param1=param1.Replace("\"","");

param1=param1.Substring(4,4) + '-' + param1.Substring(2,2) + '-' + param1.Substring(0,2) + ' ' + param1.Substring(10,2) + ':' + param1.Substring(12,2);

   System.DateTime strDate;
    if (System.DateTime.TryParseExact(param1, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out strDate))
    {
        return strDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss");
    }
    return "INVALID DATE";
}enter code here`
```